# Events emitted greater than allocation

Tags: platform-event

We are seeing our number of events emitted being greater than our allocated amount of 25k. Does anyone know how this happens? Also, we are not able to emit events right now because we are over the allocation, but Salesforce didn't enforce a hard stop at the 25k allocation.
[image]

Our second question is at what time does the event allocation reset? The countdown from the error notification doesn't appear to be accurate. I've attached screenshots for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The limit you speak of is a rolling window. If you send out 1,000 events per hour, you'll never hit the 25k limit, but your org will state you're at approximately 24,000/25,000 usage. Also, it's not a hard limit. There's a small grace window before you're cut off entirely, which is how you reached 40,000+ before you got cut off. This grace window depends on server resources and if you've purchased additional allocations. If you are consistently getting this high, salesforce.com should contact your organization to help identify if the usage can be reduced and/or if you need additional allocations.